# How to execute all the functions in a loop, where some functions are needed to be called as a callback of async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, lodash, es6-promise

I have a javascript Object which has a mix of async and sync function, I am using lodash map to execute all the functions of that object.

Below is  my code where, args.actions contains mix of async/sync functions, how can I excute action3 in .then() of action2ReturnPromise..?

Note:- I am aware of lodash map(), that order of execution is not sure when used with object/collection.

```
let { action1, action2ReturnPromise, action3}   = actionService

let args = {
        actions: {
            action1,
            action2ReturnPromise,
            action3
        },
        someExtraArgs: 'Fooo'
}
```

The actionDispatcher

```
let actionDispatcher = (args) => { // An Iterator fuction to dispatch all the actions
        _.map(args.actions, (value, key) => { //args.actions are all the actions/function to be called
        _.isFunction(svc[key]) && svc[key](args); // svc is a class which has all the functions
        });
    }
```

```
actionDispatcher(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [async functions](https://javascript.info/async-await), making even the standard function returning a promise:

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)

  alert(result); // "done!"
}

f();
```